# Figurative usage of "astride"

Tags: meaning, figurative

Can "astride" be used in the figurative meaning of "half one on side and half on the other side"?

The specific concept I'm trying to express is that a certain span of values with a certain length is centered on a given value, so I'm saying:

The range is 200 MHz astride the central frequency.

Comment: *Astride* is almost always a reference to riding (or at least sitting on something as if to ride it), and while sidebands may be figuratively "riding" a carrier, this may be taking the metaphor just a bit too far. If you are talking about modulated RF, why not call the carrier the, um, carrier, which frees up *centred* (which would be an awkward repetition in the current formulation)?

Comment: Consider:  *The range is 200 MHz (+-) the central frequency.*

Comment: @bye: I agree in saying "carrier" instead of "central frequency", but I still have the problem of saying that the range of frequencies is half on one side of the carrier and half on the other.(I know it could be easily deducted, but I have to state that clearly). Which word would you use in place of "astride"?

Comment: *Centred around*?

Comment: @ Gary's Student: thanks for your comment. I'm considering to change the sentence as a last chance if I cannot get a good word in place of "astride". Anyway, I meant that the range is 100 MHz +/- the central frequency.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Are you sure you don't mean **the range is the central frequency +/- 100 MHz**? (i.e. - if the central frequency is 500MHz, the range is 400-600MHz).

Comment: 1. You may use *astride* in a certain situation to emphasize how it happens to be, though it doesn't appear appropriate here. 2. A better (more suitable to the context) word is a better option.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers: of course! Thank you for your correction, I was misled by the previous comment! So, once and for all: the range goes from (central frequency - 100 Mhz) to (central frequency + 100 MHz).

Comment: Personally, I think adjectival ***astride*** isn't usually used in *any* such figurative contexts (though the related verb ***straddle*** often is). But for OP's *exact* context I don't really think even that works very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, no. While you can use *astride* figuratively, I don't see how it can fit here. I would instead use

> The range spans 200 MHz on either side of the central frequency.

or

> The range extends 200 MHz on either side of the central frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Astride can be used figuratively. See this example from the [Oxford leaner's dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/astride_1).

> with one leg on each side of something
>
> - to sit astride a horse/bike/chair
> - **(figurative) a town astride the river**

However in your case *astride* would be incorrect. The range is not *astride* the central frequency as it encompasses it, rather than residing either side of it.

Your range is ±100MHz from the central frequency.